# Kubernetes readiness and liveliness endpoints being called from the pod itself

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I have a cluster running linkerd and several pods which are all meshed. One pod has strange behavior in that I am seeing multiple calls for liveliness and readiness. One originates from the kubelet, the other originates from the pod itself.

I installed the linkerd debug container into the pod to verify this. Here is a sample of the debug logs showing `/readyz` being called twice as described:

```
61500 8585.442787151  10.56.108.1 → 10.56.108.3  HTTP 177 GET /readyz HTTP/1.1
61501 8585.442829241  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.1  TCP 68 5200 → 53564 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=110 Win=43648 Len=0 TSval=885352394 TSecr=1855609776
61502 8585.443101851  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.3  HTTP 158 GET /readyz HTTP/1.1
61503 8585.443136941  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.3  TCP 68 5200 → 49518 [ACK] Seq=178 Ack=181 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=2132012422 TSecr=2132012422
61504 8585.443699891  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.3  HTTP 245 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
61505 8585.443706991  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.3  TCP 68 49518 → 5200 [ACK] Seq=181 Ack=355 Win=43648 Len=0 TSval=2132012423 TSecr=2132012423
61506 8585.443804231  10.56.108.3 → 10.56.108.1  HTTP 198 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I don't see this behavior on other pods in the cluster, is there anything that could be configured in linkerd that might create this issue?

Comment: i guess the pod isnt restarting ?

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you reliably reproduce the behavior? If you could you share some details on how to do that?

Comment: That TCP dump looks to me like you're seeing the kubelet's probe hit the linkerd proxy and then seeing linkerd forward that request to the app container on the same pod.

Does your application see both requests or only one? How did you notice this behavior? Is it causing problems?